# notepad++ puts text after a carriage return on a new line

Tags: notepad++, carriage-return, line-numbers

I have two files, A and B, of equal length. The n-th line in the file A corresponds to the n-th line in the file B. In file A sometimes the carriage return was used to overwrite text on the same line. When opening the files in notepad++, file A appears to have more lines than file B, because text after a carriage return is placed on a new line and notepad++ increments the line number. This makes it difficult to find corresponding lines between file A and B.

An example

```
line number|File A    ||line number|File B
      1    |a\r\n     ||      1    |x\r\n
      2    |b\r       ||      2    |y\r\n
      3    |c\r       ||      3    |z\r\n
      4    |d\r\n     ||
      5    |e\r\n     ||
```

Both files in reality only have three lines. 'a\r\n' corresponds to 'x\r\n', 'b\rc\rd\r\n' (or simply 'd\r\n') corresponds to 'y\r\n' and 'e\r\n' corresponds to 'z\r\n'. However, in file A 'b\rc\rd\r\n' starts on line number 2 and finishes on line number 4 due to the carriage returns.

Is it possible for notepad++ to apply the carriage returns, such that file A only shows 'a' and 'd' and 'e'? If not, is it possible that the line numbers only increment after a newline symbol, such that the line numbers between files A and B are aligned?

Comment: That's some legacy data you got there, son.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove all the `\r` chars to quickly align both files. Go to "replace", switch to extended mode, and replace `\r` with nothing. Then [Edit]>[EOL Conversion]>[Windows Format] to get back to \r\n line endings (you'd be left with \n's only).

If you wan't to "apply" all carriage returns, you'll have to use RegEx. Switch to "regular expression" in replace, and replace this with nothing:

```
^.+\r(?!\n)
```

It will remove all `\r` that is not followed by `\n` and the entire line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I believe applying your regex is not the same as applying the carriage return, i.e. writing the next character at the start of the line. For example, 'abc\rx\r\n' should result in 'xbc\r\n', while your regex would give 'x\r\n'.

Comment: @MAcabot Don't you mean it should result in `abx\r\n`? Then `.\r(?!\n)` should do it?

Comment: @MAcabot You're right. In this case you can't use regex, I'm afraid, and you'll have to solve this programatically...